# HTML number type inputs increment/decrement button continuosly increases the number

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

I am having a situation that is difficult to investigate/explain.

I have created a number input field inside an ant design modal box. I can type the number inside and it works fine. but if I click on the increment/decrement, it increases or decreases continuously until I **focus out** of the input field.

I'm using ReactJs and this input field is not bound to any state variable.

```
<label> Hello: </label>
<input type="number" id="ambiguous_id"></input>
```

I do not knowingly use any direct dom manipulation libraries like JQuery.
the following gif will describe its behaviour furthermore.

[image]

further observations: Material UI input number input fields also show this same behaviour

Comment: how are you increasing/decreasing the value? I mean the code

Comment: I haven't written any logic to do that by code. It's purely just a number input. just the input.  I also tested on the brave browser (without any extensions). same behaviour.

Comment: do you have a sandbox?